# Why must a minimum of 6 characters be changed when editing typesetting errors?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, character-limit

I've had some problems when helping to fix minor typesetting errors that I am required to edit a minimum number of characters, but usually only less than 6 are needed to change. What's the reason for the limit?